# python eval() to only accept conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements, eval

I have text input in this form from a textbox:

`gzip == True`

`gzip == False and count >= 100`

`gzip == True or msg == "Hello!"`

I use eval() to get the result of the condition. However there are the obvious "security concerns" with eval like code injection.

Is there any way I can limit it to conditions? I dont need it for anything else.

Comment: Use a seperate function to validate the string first. Check for certain operators/keywords that shouldn't exist, disallow the single = operator. Once you've validated the string, pass it to eval.
Of course, there is still a risk that some clever person might figure out a way round this.

Comment: Parse the string using the `ast` module, and then interpret the AST explicitly for those kind of operations you need to support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @scotty3785 mentioned you need to create a separate function for checking the input for certain operations you need. Then you pass the input to `ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)`. I would avoid using `eval()` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,with eval there are security issues.I think that you should use pyparsing to parse the expression into tokens list and after that deal with tokens.You can find more 
http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 1):

`pyparsing` is a great option. If you don't want to define a grammar and all that jazz though, another option you could try is this:

```
safe_variables = {} # use this to define safe functions and variables
code = "...."
eval(code, {"__builtins__": None}, safe_variables)
```

By passing a dictionary with the **builtins** explicitly set None, you are ensuring that the code has NO access to the builtin functions of Python e.g. (abs, open, filter, etc...). If it's not explicitly set to None then the current globals will be copied.

That locks down the code alot. Next, explicitly list the variables and functions that you want the code to have access to in the `safe_variables` dictionary.